# deleting folders in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, regex

i'm trying to delete in gnu/linux all folders inside another folder that start with a "." (dot), for that i'm using the find utility, this is what i have:

```
find . -iname ^\..* -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

but it doesn't do anything :(. I'm already tested the regular expression and works well. Any help please??

thank's a lot for your time.

Comment: Be _very_ careful. There is a `.` and `..` file in every directory which will likely cause you grief when you `rm -rf` it :-)

Comment: thanks for the information, i read it too late :( i deleted a very important work i was doing, so all again :(. But i will keep in mind the next time

Answer (score 5):

`find` uses globbing syntax, and you can use `-type d` to find just directories:

```
find . -type d -name '.?*' | vim -
```

You need to be **extremely** careful when globbing or using regex to find `.hidden` files, as you can quite easily pick up `.` and delete your whole folder, or even worse, match `..` and you delete your whole parent folder. Consider the consequences of the following command:

```
/home/someuser bash$ rm -rf .*
```

Comment: +1 for the "be careful" comment alone! I'm not usually prescient but I saw much angst and gnashing of teeth in fkn_man's future :-)

Answer (score 1):

`-name` and `-iname` use globs, not regexs. Try `-regex` or `-iregex` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -iname ".*" -not -iname "." -not -iname ".."
```

Comment: Find doesn't list .., so you only need to exclude the first.

Comment: You don't need to exclude either with `-mindepth 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) is an option, you can simply use: `print **/.*(/)` or `rm` of course :)